# Use same docker image tag in two different jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I have 2 jenkins pipelines, in one pipeline I am building image and pushing image to docker registry. I am using BUILD_NUMBER for tagging the new build image.

```
dockerImage = docker.build("springboot:${BUILD_NUMBER}")
dockerImage.push()
```

In the second pipeline, I am using sshagent plugin to login into host machines and running docker pull command to pull the same image that I build and push in first pipeline above.

```
sshagent(['aws-private-access-key']){
     sh "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no 223024520@10.225.1.21 docker pull 
     springboot:${BUILD_NUMBER}"
}
```

Problem with the second pipeline is that, the BUILD_NUMBER for both pipeline can be different from each others, and when I run second pipeline it is not able to pull the image because tag of docker image in registry differs from the current BUILD_NUMBER.

I am looking for a solution how this can be solved. I know "latest" tag but I want to keep my images versions with proper tagging.

Comment: If you're triggering the second pipeline from the first pipeline, then you can pass the BUILD_NUMBER of the first pipeline as a parameter to the second pipeline.

Comment: @bilcy no both pipelines are seperate. I am now trying with global variable inside Jenkins but i am not sure if there is anyway to update the global variable from script

Comment: I don't know what your use case is and how important it is to only use BUILD_NUMBER as the image tag. If that doesn't work out for you then you can use your git commit hash as the tag for docker image tag and that can be used in both the Jenkins jobs.